# How do add a button to go back to another page in oracle apex interactive grid

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I want to add a customized button in oracle apex interactive grid to allow users to go back to the previous page. Can someone explain how I can do this in javascript? Thanks

Comment: `window.document.location = document.referrer;`

Comment: @RezaSaadati using document.referrer is not a good idea because it is not as reliable as history.back() because it is for example gone after reload

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the previous page"? Do you mean the page in the same application they navigated from, or any other page in any other application, or from the previous page in the breadcrumb hierarchy? Also, why does it need to be in the interactive grid, specifically?

Answer (score 3):

Without javascript (recommended):

1. Create your button, let's say **BTN_PREVIOUS**, and a hidden page item, **P1_PREVIOUS_PAGE**
2. Create a new branch:

**Point:** After Porcessing

**Behavior Type:** Page Identified by Item (Show only)

**Item:** Select your hidden item created on step 1 (P1_PREVIOUS_PAGE)

**Server-side Condition**: When Button Pressed, BTN_PREVIOUS

Now for every page that calls this one, you have to set the item **P1_PREVIOUS_PAGE** with the number of the calling page. There's innumerable ways to to this (through declarative list entries, URL, javascript), I recommend you to read https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39147/concept_url.htm

**Obs:** if you do the steps above, make sure that every other process, computation and branches have a server side condition, because this method relies on submitting the page and you don't want your "Previous" button triggering any other logic that you have already created.

---

With javascript:

1. Create your button, let's say **BTN_PREVIOUS**;
2. Create a dynamic action

*When:* **Event:** Click

**Selection Type:** Button

**Button:** BTN_PREVIOUS

Inside the dynamic action create a true action:

**Action:** Execute JavaScript code

**Code:** history.back()

Although the javascript way is simpler, it's always preferable to use what the tool (APEX) has to offer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`history.back()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history) or if you want to go multiple steps back [`history.go(-2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history)