# How to redirect to previous page after clicking "ok" on the apex.confirm message box in oracle apex dynamic action

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-18.2

How to navigate back to the previous page after I hit ok on the confirm message box on apex. I used a dynamic action on the delete button but it only deletes the record not navigate back to the previous page. Is my code below correct?

```
if(apex.confirm(htmldb_delete_message,'DELETE') == true)
{
   apex.navigation.redirect(window.history.back());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the default delete button that is created by the form creation wizard, then on the button properties you'll see that the button's behavior target is defined by a javascript which prompts a confirmation window. After the user hits "OK" on that window, the page is **submitted** so your delete process can execute.

Trying to execute a javascript code before that to force the navigation may be a bad idea and you would have to restructure your delete process to be processed at the right point

Try to create a **branch** (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39147/nav_branch_using.htm#HTMDB25149) instead of using a dynamic action to navigate back to previous page. You can configure it to occur "after processing" and either manually set the page that you to go back to or use a hidden item to always go back to the page which the user came from as described in here: [How do add a button to go back to another page in oracle apex interactive grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57103876/how-do-add-a-button-to-go-back-to-another-page-in-oracle-apex-interactive-grid)